# Stack ImageButtons on top and side by side to each other

Tags: android

I have the following **ImageButton** format:

```
<ImageButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

And here is the container layout **(notice the id)**

```
       <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <GridLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      ---->         android:id="@+id/ADDING IMGBUTTONS HERE"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                </GridLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/ADDING IMGBUTTONS HERE"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

The imagebuttons get added, but only side by side and eventually **continue get added off screen.** The designated space for the image buttons is available for a grid of 2x2x2x2x2, so that's what I want, two images by row. What is happening now is "infinite" images by row, although I can only see two because the others get added offscreen. How can I avoid this in the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your layout to:

```
<GridLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"  
    android:rowCount="2">    

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_row="0"      
        android:layout_column="0"   
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_row="0"         
        android:layout_column="1"      
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: omfg, amazing... tysm